# Translating Python code to Oz

Tags: python, oz, mozart

Can somebody help me in translating this piece of Python code to Oz language?

```
def rep_subset_conditional(S, tset, index, t, count):
    for i in xrange(index, len(S)):
        tset += [S[i]]
        tsum = sum(tset)
        if tsum == t:
            print tset
            count += 1
            tset.remove(S[i])
            return count
        elif tsum > t:
            tset.remove(S[i])
            return count
        else:
            count=rep_subset_conditional(S, tset, i, t, count)
            tset.remove(S[i])
    return count
```

This code simply counts and prints all the subsets(with repetition of elements) of a given set whose sum equals t. 
Below is a trial run of this code:

```
>>> rep_subset_conditional([1, 5, 10, 25, 50], [], 0, 10, 0)
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5]
    [5, 5]
    [10]
    4
```

`t` here was 10 
`S` was subset `[1, 5, 10, 25, 50]`
I want to translate this program into Oz. But I'm unable to do that correctly. Please help!
This is what all I tried:

```
declare Rep T1 T2 Sum
fun {Rep L S MainList AuxList C}
   case L of nil then C
   [] H|T then
      {Browse H|AuxList}
      if {Sum H|AuxList} == S then
      T1={Rep MainList S MainList H|AuxList C+1}
      {Rep T S MainList AuxList T1}
      else
      if {Sum H|AuxList} < S then
         T2 = {Rep MainList S MainList AuxList C}
         {Rep T S MainList AuxList T2}
      end
      end      
   end
end
fun {Sum L}
  case L of nil then 0
  [] H|T then
     H + {Sum T}
  end
end
```

Comment: What did you try? What isn't working? Be more specific!

Comment: Well, I am new to Oz(and functional programming in general) I posted all what i tried. I could not manage to do recursion with looping both at same time in Oz(without using `for` construct of Oz).

Comment: You are not handling the case `{Sum H|AuxList} > S`, so in this case the `Rep` function does not know what to return.